# Unlit area of 3D textured object to use specific colour - Shader

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader

I'm hoping to make the unlit area of a 3D textured object change to a specific colour.

Hopefully this pic can explain a little better.
[image]

So far I've found a shader that would turn an unlit area transparent, which is cool but not exactly right. I'm fairly sure it wouldn't be a big stretch to make this turn into a specific colour instead of transparent, do you have any pointers or suggestions to get this effect? Or if you know a shader that already does this that would be amazing!

(this is the shader that makes something transparent by the way)

http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/283985/a-shader-with-transparent-lit-area.html

Thanks very much in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you just want to 'lerp' between your "unlitColor" and "litColor" using dot(normal, lightDirection) as the lerp factor.

Something like:

```
float nDotL = saturate(dot(surfaceNormal, vectorToLight));
float3 unlitColor = float3(0, 0, 0.5); // Or whatever color you like
float3 litColor = colorFromTheTexture;
float3 finalColor = lerp(unlitColor, litColor, nDotL);
```

Comment: Hi Adam, thanks for taking the time to reply. I was wondering if it would be possible to break down your code for me. What is surfaceNormal and vectorToLight? And would this code be written into the shader itself? Thanks again!

Comment: SurfaceNormal would be a normalised 3D vector (direction) pointing away from the surface of the object. This data would usually be stored per vertex and come from the vertex buffer and be interpolated per pixel. VectorToLight is another 3D normalised vector pointing towards the light from the point in world space that the pixel lies. Both are pretty standard concepts usually denoted by N and L.